# How to put Bitmaps in the middle of SurfaceView with space between them

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-custom-view, android-bitmap

[image: My screen]

If look very carefully you see that the bitmaps aren't in the middle of screen and I don't know what to do to put them in the middle of all kinds of screen with a space between them, that need to exchange according to screen width.

My Code:

```
int SPACEBETWEEN = 80;

for(int i = -1; i < 2; i++) { 

    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp,SPACEBETWEEN * i + canvas.getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2, null);
}
```

My width screen is 480

Comment: Use a `RelativeLayout`?...

Comment: I normally use **strings** for that. I have an array of strings (say "\u25cf \u25cb \u25cb", "\u25cb \u25cf \u25cb", "\u25cb \u25cb \u25cf") and change the string accordingly. Being `\u25cf` a **filled** circle and `\u25cb` an **empty** one

Comment: Yes, but I am using a custom surface view too.

Comment: But what's the Cf and Cb and in this case how I will make to the values exchange according to screen width ?

Answer (score 3):

You're not negatively offsetting half the width of the bitmaps themselves. You need something like `- bmp.getWidth()/2` somewhere in your formula (ditto for height).

Comment: You won't believe, but the bmp.getWidth()/2 is equals to screen.getWidth()/2

Comment: Not sure how you're creating your bitmaps -- feel free to show us -- but you can decode them from a file with a definite resolution. If you're creating the bitmaps from a separate canvas, this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013725/converting-a-canvas-into-bitmap-image-in-android) shows you how to set the resolution of the resulting bitmap.

Comment: I am getting the bmp with this: 
 bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.small_empty_ball);

Comment: Hmmm . . . click on the images in your drawables folder and check the resolution. Perhaps they need downscaling/cropping. Perhaps you're storing them with a lot of padding. Some automatic scaling will occur according to this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047748/why-does-bitmapfactory-decoderesource-scale-my-image) unless you put them in a no-dpi folder, which is typically *not* what you want to do.

Comment: Man I am so sorry for that, but let me tell you what was the small problem and how I solved it.

The problem was that the image had a big transparency and the circle wasn't centralized. I just open the image in PSD, remove the exaggerated transparency, centralized the circle and subtract the "- bmp.getWidth()/2" in my formula how you told me.