# BitmapFactory.decodeResource out of memory

Tags: android, bitmap

First off, I'm aware that the Android imposes some severe constraints on loading Bitmaps. I'm trying to understand if there is some simple way to load and use the bitmap I need.

I have a 2800 x 2800 ARGB image that I need to be able to load, zoom into and pan around.  A 2800 x 2880 ARGB image should take around 31 MB in memory. I realize that is big.  However, when I try to load it I get an error saying that

Failed to allocate a 125,440,012 byte allocation...

I'm curious why it is allocating a chuck of memory around 4 times the size needed to hold the image.  Is that expected or is something wrong happening?  I'm loading the image using:

```
BitmapFactory.decodeResource( getResources(), resID, options );
```

Loading this image works fine on all iOS devices I've tried it on and it works fine on a Nexus 2013 tablet.  However, it is failing on an Android phone I have for testing.

I would certainly like to avoid loading subregions of the images and managing them (using something like BitmapRegionDecoder).  Any thoughts on something simple to try?

Comment: What resource directory is your image in? You might be getting a [scaled image by default](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23047893/1676363)

Answer (score 1):

The Android docs has a simple guide about [loading bitmpas efficiently](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html#load-bitmap). Basically you need to load a scaled down version of your original bitmap in RAM, because you generally don't need to load a very big bitmap only to show it in a region of your screen (suppose your screen has a max resolution of 1920x1080, so you are wasting memory loading a 2800x2800 bitmap).

Answer (score 0):

I decided to solve it by trying to load the full resolution image first.  This succeeds on most devices.  I do it in a try block and catch the OutOfMemory exception.  In the catch block I then load it at reduced resolution which will work in a pinch.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this method:

```
private static Bitmap getBitmapFromResources(int resourceId) {

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
    options.inDither = true;

    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(AppController.getInstance().getResources(), resourceId, options);
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        // do something ...
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

and call it with:

```
Bitmap images = getBitmapFromResources(R.drawable.image_in_res);
```

where

```
AppController.getInstance().getResources()
```

is your app Context
and

```
R.drawable.image_in_res
```

your image in /res/... folder