# App crashes when loading map: Textures with dimensions 16x256 are larger than the maximum supported size 0x0 in android studio

Tags: android, google-maps

My app was running fine yesterday. I woke up this morning to continue and it keeps crashing when loading the `MapView`. 
The app loads the map right after the user signs in but now, it just crashes with the same error. This is the error message:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 272
              Process: com.emyce.ridesgh.ridesgh, PID: 6448
              java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Textures with dimensions16x256 are larger than  the maximum supported size 0x0
                  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.ah.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@14366052@14.3.66 (040700-213742215):72)
                  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.aj.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@14366052@14.3.66 (040700-213742215):46)
                  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.aj.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@14366052@14.3.66 (040700-213742215):4)
                  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.g.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@14366052@14.3.66 (040700-213742215):44)
                  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.bs.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@14366052@14.3.66 (040700-213742215):80)
                  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.bb.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@14366052@14.3.66 (040700-213742215):84).
```

I've been searching google for a solution to this but found none.

Comment: What version of `GoogleMap` are your using? And can you paste the lines went wrong?

Comment: I'm using the version 16.0.0. I can't figure out exactly which line. I've been going over the code to see if a resource i used has that dimension but there isn't anything like that

Comment: Have you figured out this issue?

Answer (score 0):

When I found this exact same error I found this question, and [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047748/why-does-bitmapfactory-decoderesource-scale-my-image) older one. Non with solution that worked for me. So I started to read the documentation for map overlays. My image was 3175x2245 and that was the problem.

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/GroundOverlayOptions.html#image(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptor)) of `GroundOverlayOptions`

> To load an image as a texture (which is used to draw the image on a
>   map), it must be converted into an image with sides that are powers of
>   two.

So you have to convert your images width and height to be powers of two. In my case the compromise was a 2048x2048 square (cropped the original images to have space on top and bottom). And it worked. Some phones doesn't care about this, others do.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing my local Java version to another one that seems more adapted to Android development (Zulu 11), cleaned my build folder and rebuilt the app