# Android Studio Mapactivity always crashes

Tags: java, api, google-maps, android-studio, illegalargumentexception

It's my first time that I am using Maps in my Android Studio project.
My problem is that I always get the same error code:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Textures with dimensions16x256 are
>   larger than  the maximum supported size 0x0
>           at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.ai.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@17785052@17.7.85
>   (040700-253824076):75)
>           at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.ak.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@17785052@17.7.85
>   (040700-253824076):52)
>           at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.ak.(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@17785052@17.7.85
>   (040700-253824076):4)
>           at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.f.(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@17785052@17.7.85
>   (040700-253824076):44)
>           at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.bx.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@17785052@17.7.85
>   (040700-253824076):82)
>           at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.bi.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@17785052@17.7.85
>   (040700-253824076):90)

It would be nice if someone could help me.

Comment: It looks like this error was reported in this other SO question and has no answer yet https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53024234/app-crashes-when-loading-map-textures-with-dimensions-16x256-are-larger-than-th

Comment: Can you please post your build.gradle and code that is causing this error? If your play services' version is 16.0.0 or lower and you're targeting API level 28 or above please [try this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/config#specify_requirement_for_apache_http_legacy_library).

Comment: I have solved the problem! The reason why I got this error was because of the emulator I have used. Since I switched to an other emulator it works fine.

Comment: Glad to hear! Thanks for your update. :)